# Add a second button after first is clicked in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with adding a second button "Proceed" to appear only after "I Agree" button is clicked by the user. The "Proceed" button should take the user to a specific URL. https://www.google.com for example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p> Click following button to agree to the terms and conditions.</p>
<p id="demo" style="color:white">User Agreed to terms and conditions.</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "I Agree";
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">I Agree</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.style.color = "green";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```js
function agree() {
  document.getElementById("proceed").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p> Click following button to agree to the terms and conditions.</p>

  <button onclick="agree()">I Agree</button>

  <a id="proceed" style="display: none;" href="https://www.google.com">Proceed</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a new button using the `document.createElement` method, then give it some properties and append it to a parent element in the DOM.

You can navigate to a new page using the `location` property of the (default) window object. (Note that the line that handles browser navigation is commented out below because Stack Overflow snippets are sandboxed so the code would fail in this environment.)

This demo uses a "`buttonContainer`" div that is responsible for handling clicks on its child buttons, calling the appropriate function in each case.

```js
const buttonsContainer = document.getElementById("buttons-container");
buttonsContainer.addEventListener("click", handleButtonClicks);

function handleButtonClicks(event){
  if(event.target.id == "agree-btn"){ addProceedBtn(event); }
  else if(event.target.id == "proceed-btn"){ proceed(event); }
}

function addProceedBtn(event){
  const
    proceedBtn = document.createElement("button");
    proceedBtn.id = "proceed-btn";
    proceedBtn.textContent = "Proceed";
    buttonsContainer.appendChild(proceedBtn);
}

function proceed(event){
  console.log("We got one!");
  // location = "https://my-other-page.com"; // Redirects browser  
}
```

```html
<p> Click following button to agree to the terms and conditions.</p>
<div id="buttons-container">
  <button id="agree-btn">I Agree</button>
</div>
```

Comment: on clicking proceed , he wants to navigate to google.com

Comment: Thanks, I added a line for that

Comment: mate do we need anything else just to navigate , as it says refuse to connect ?

Comment: Do you mean in general or from a Stack Overflow snippet in particular? I don't think Stack Overflow will let us redirect each others' browsers from snippets (and if it's not obvious, my demo url, `http://my-other-page.com/`, is not a real web page.) But setting `window.location="whatever"` should do the job in the wild.

Comment: may be i was using fiddle and it is behaving that way ....

Comment: Yeah, I bet that's sandboxed the same way SO is

Comment: Thank's for the clarity :)

Answer (score 0):

In this code, there is a hidden button when page is loaded. After you click the "Agree" button, "Proceed" button will be appeared.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p> Click following button to agree to the terms and conditions.</p>
    <p id="demo" style="color:white">User Agreed to terms and conditions.</p>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">I Agree</button>
    <button id="proceed-button" onclick="window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'" style="display:none">Proceed</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.style.color = "green";
  document.getElementById("proceed-button").style.display = 'inline-block';
  
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" id="check"> 
<p> Click following button to agree to the terms and conditions.</p>
<p id="demo" style="color:white">User Agreed to terms and conditions.</p>
<button id="btn" onclick="myFunction()">Proceed</button>
<script>
  document.querySelector('#btn').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
  document.querySelector('#check').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.srcElement.checked);
    if(event.srcElement.checked) {
      document.querySelector('#btn').removeAttribute("disabled");
    } else {
       document.querySelector('#btn').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  })
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    x.style.color = "green";
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```